# Gwt MouseDownHandler usage

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-2.2

I am trying to figure out to use a MouseDownHandler with a ListBox.

I have the following code:

```
myCombo.addMouseDownHandler(new MouseDownHandler(){
  Window.alert("WORKING");
});
```

I get this error however.

> The method
>   addMouseDownHandler(MouseDownHandler)
>   in the type FocusWidget is not
>   applicable for the arguments (new
>   MouseDownHandler(){})

Comment: What type is the widget? GWT doesn't have a ComboBox widget type.

Comment: Sorry ListBox.I am used to flash heh.

Comment: the example code shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MouseDownHandler` has to implement the `onMouseDown` method:

```
myCombo.addMouseDownHandler(new MouseDownHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event) {
    // Handle mouse down event
  }
});
```

Comment: this looks like the problem/solution.